# IPersistStreamInit::Save() not working in IE9?

Tags: save, iwebbrowser2, ihtmldocument2

This code worked for IE8 and earlier. For IE9 it seems that IPersistStreamInit::Save() returns E_NOTIMPL. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
HRESULT CHtmlCtrl::GetDocumentHTML(CString& strHTML) const
{
    HRESULT hr = E_NOINTERFACE;

    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> spHTMLDocument;
    GetHtmlDocument()->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (LPVOID*)&spHTMLDocument);
    if (spHTMLDocument)
    {
        CComQIPtr<IPersistStreamInit> spPSI;
        spPSI = spHTMLDocument;
        if (spPSI)
        {
            CStreamOnCString stream;
            hr = spPSI->Save(static_cast<IStream*>(&stream), FALSE);
            if (hr == S_OK)
            {
                if (!stream.CopyData(strHTML))
                    hr = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
            }
        }
    }

    return hr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug in the MFC as described and confirmed [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/687736#mfc-class-cstreamoncstring-stops-working-with-ie9). [Fixed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/06/14/what-bugs-were-fixed-in-mfc-in-visual-studio-2012/) in Visual Studio 2012 RTM.